# Flexbox, проблема с изображением

Tags: css, flexbox

Пытаюсь сделать так как в макете
[image: Макет]
Но получается вот так.

```css
.container8 {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.photo {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-basis: 475.5px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="container8">

    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="photo"><img src="https://img1.goodfon.ru/wallpaper/big/a/69/kartinka-3d-dikaya-koshka.jpg" alt=""></div>

  </div>

</section>
```

[image: Моя вёрстка]

Answer (score 1):

475.5 * 4 = 1902

во-вторых сделайте так

```
.photo {flex-basis: 25%}
.photo img {max-width: 100%}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
  .photo {flex-basis: 33%}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .photo {flex-basis: 50%}
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .photo {flex-basis: 100%}
}
```

Потом в тэг `head` в файл `html` кладем следующую строку, чтобы адаптивность работала:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: Если ставишь max-width: 100%, то пропадает адаптивность. Есть ещё решение?

Comment: как это адаптивность пропадает? что значит пропадает? @ВладимирБогданович я вам поправил код

Comment: Я просто хотел узнать есть ли способ без медиа запросов решить эту проблему. Ну походу нету всё равно спасибо большое

Comment: @ВладимирБогданович - есть. Нужно знать, какая ширина контейнера у вас. Если она 1600px, тогда `.photo {flex-basis: 400px}` и все. То есть делим контейнер на 4. Но тогда у вас просто при ширине 1599 уже блоков станет 3 в ряду. Лучше с медиа писать, это более резиново